# Dynamic Where clause in Lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, lambda, where-clause

I have some filter parameters in the `Controller` of an `ASP.NET MVC` project and I need to create `Where` clause dynamically according to these parameters. If `isActive` parameter is true, it will get the records having the `StatusId = 1`. There are also `userName` and `labId` parameters in the method that should be matched in the `Where` clause.

```
public ActionResult GetStudents(int labId, string userName, bool isAll)
{
    var allRecords = repository.Students;
    //If isAll, get all the records having StatusId = 1
    var result = allRecords.Where(m => (isAll) || m.StatusId == 1); 
    //??? 
}
```

I use the filter above, but I have no idea what is the most suitable way (conventions) for multiple parameters in order to fetch the result fast. Any idea?

**Note:** I want to **filter for all of three parameters** and Where clause should contain all of the combinations according to the parameter's values (also is null or empty).

Comment: `if (isAll) { allRecords = allRecords.Where(m => m.StatusId == 1; } else { ..}`

Comment: Multiple `Where` clauses are joined together by *ands*. So you can add them as you need as @StephenMuecke showed.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Could you please post the full clause by adding it to other parameters? Because labId and userName combinations make me confused.

Comment: @ClintEastwood, You have not explained what combinations you want. Do  you also want to filter by `userName` if that is not `null`? in which case add `if (userName != null) { allRecords = allRecords.Where(...); }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, by the way, it should be `if (!isAll)  allRecords = allRecords.Where(m => m.StatusId == 1; `. And no need for `else`. I think the comment (*If isAll, get all the records having StatusId = 1*) mislead you, I say that according to `allRecords.Where(m => (isAll) || m.StatusId == 1);`

Comment: @AdilMammadov, no its `if (isAll)` :) And OP has not given enough info to know if an `else` clause is needed or not

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, I want to filter for all of three parameters and Where clause should contain all of the combinations according to the parameter's values (also is null or empty).

Comment: @ClintEastwood, That depends on if the value of `labId` and `userName` are both provided or not. If they could be not provided, then just use 3 if clauses (it will build the sql query for you)

Comment: All of three parameters will be provided and I think it is better to use default values on the method as **public ActionResult GetStudents(int labId = 0, string userName = "", bool isAll = false)** Is that smart or nonsense?

Comment: That won´t change how your predicate shoulkd work. You should make a switch on the arguments anyway, no matter if you have a default-value for them or not.

Comment: Since `userName` can be `null`, then you need the 3 `if` clauses (othewise `.Where(x => x.UserName == userName)` would return no records.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Could you post the full answer please? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @ClintEastwood, You need to tell us what properties of your model you searching. I'm guessing its `UserName == userName`? And what about `labId` - does you model have a property for that, and can its value be `0`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke UserName == userName / LabId = labId (labId parameter can be null) / isAll == true (default falue can be given as false). Thanks a lot...

Comment: Then I would use `var allRecords = repository.Students; if (isAll) { allRecords = allRecords.Where(m => m.StatusId == 1; }; if (userName != null) { allRecords = allRecords.Where(m => m.UserName  == userName ); } if (labId.HasValue) { allRecords = allRecords.Where(m => m.LabId== labId); } return View(allRecords);` (and that assumes the parameter is `int? labId` (nullable))

Comment: @StephenMuecke You rock! That is the most suitable and smart way for dynamically create Where clause. Thanks a lot Stephen...

Comment: your `labId` is of type `int` so it doesn´t have a `HasValue`-property. I assume you actually want `int?` which *can* be `null`.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Thanks...

Comment: @StephenMuecke Do you have any knowledge about **jquery.cookie**? Could you please have a look at [Cannot retain checkbox value using jquery.cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39889632/cannot-retain-checkbox-value-using-jquery-cookie)? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate linq-methods as they all return an `IEnumerable<T>` and are combined using something like an SQL-`And` (dependinng on what LINQ-provider you use):

```
IEnumerable<Student> result = allRecords;
if(labelId.HasValue) 
    result = result.Where(x => x.LabelId == labelId);
else
    result = result.Where(x => x.LabelId == 0); // or whatever your default-behaviour is

if(isAll)
    result = result.Where(x => x.StatusId == 1);
else 
    result = result.Where(x => x.StatusId == 0); // or whateever your default-behaviour is when isAll is false

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) 
    result = result.Where(x => x.Name == userName);
else 
    result = result.Where(x => x.Name == "Claus"); // or whatever the default-behaviour is when the param isn´t set
```

Comment: AIthough I followed the approach shown by StephenMuecke, vote up your answer as this is also useful. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Record>();

if(isAll)
  predicate = predicate.AND(d => d.StatusId ==1);

 predicate = predicate.AND(d => d.labID == labid && d.username = username);

 return allRecords.Where(predicate);`
```

You can use a [predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I do not think to use an external tool as predicate builder.

Comment: And if you look at https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/699 you will see predicate builder taken a little bit further.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
public ActionResult GetStudents(int labId, string userName, bool isAll)
{
    var allRecords = repository.Students;
    //If isAll, get all the records having StatusId = 1
    if (isAll) 
    { 
       var result = allRecords.Where(m => m.StatusId == 1  && m.UserName == userName  && m.LabId == labId); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
       // do else things
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the full clause by adding it to other parameters? Because labId and userName combinations make me confused.

Comment: AIthough I followed the approach shown by StephenMuecke, vote up your answer as this is also useful. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

you need something like below

```
public ActionResult GetStudents(int labId, string userName, bool isAll)
{
    var allRecords = repository.Students;
    //If isAll, get all the records having StatusId = 1
    if (isAll) 
    { 
        var result = allRecords.Where(m => m.StatusId == 1 
                                            && m.LabId == labId 
                                            && m.UserName == username);
        //or
        var result = from record in allRecords
                         where record != null &&
                               record.StatusId == 1
                               && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(record.UserName)
                               && record.UserName.Equals(username)
                               && record.Labid = labId
                         select record;
    } 
    else 
    { 
       // do else things
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to filter for all of three parameters and Where clause should contain all of the combinations according to the parameter's values (also is null or empty).

Comment: you can chain all your Boolean conditions like shown above.

Comment: AIthough I followed the approach shown by StephenMuecke, vote up your answer as this is also useful. Thanks...