# Cannot retain checkbox value using jquery.cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, jquery-cookie

I use `jQuery DataTable` and there is a `checkbox` on the toolbar that is used for retrieving all records or not. As [stateSave](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) feature of `DataTable` does not work properly, I tried to use [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/jquery.cookie.js) in order to keep the checkbox value after reloading the `DataTable` (because the checkbox is redrawn dynamically on every reload) as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable( {

        //code omitted for brevity
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajaxSource": "/Student/GetStudents",
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            /* Add some extra data to the sender */
            aoData.push({ "name": "isAll", "value": $("#cbIsAll").is(":checked") });
            $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
                /* Do whatever additional processing you want on the callback, then tell DataTables */
                fnCallback(json);
            });
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
            $("div.toolbar").html('<input type="checkbox" id="cbIsAll" name="demo" /> Get all records');
        }
    });


    $(document).on('change', '#cbIsAll', function () {
        var isClicked = $('#cbIsAll').is(':checked') ? true : false;
        $.cookie('clicked', isClicked, { expires: 1 }); // expires in 1 day
        table.ajax.reload();
        $('#cbIsAll')[0].checked = ($.cookie('clicked') == "true") ? true : false;
    });     

});
```

After debugging the code I saw that although the `$('#cbIsAll')[0].checked` line is executed properly as true, the `checkbox` lost value later than this line. Could you please clarify me about where the mistake is? Or is there a better and smart way to keep the `checkbox` value?

Comment: why don't you use `prop('checked')`?

Comment: For instead of which line?

Comment: the last line of the change event

Comment: I changed it to **$('#cbIsAll').prop("checked") = ($.cookie('clicked') == "true") ? true : false;** but it did not make any sense. Any other idea?

Comment: damn man did you even read a little about what prop does lol :)

Comment: `$('#cbIsAll').prop("checked",$.cookie('clicked') == "true") ? true : false);`

Comment: Thanks but **$('#cbIsAll').prop("checked", $.cookie('clicked'))** returns **m.fn.init[1]** instead of "true" or true. Is there a revision to be done?

Comment: you are a hard egg man why are you checking the checbox in the change event and not when the page is loaded?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you are right. But when datatable is reload page is not loaded. If I am wrong, could you please post the answer you mean? Thanks in advance master :)

Comment: how an earth datatables is loaded if the page isn't loaded first :)))

Comment: If only the datatable is refreshed (not the whole page), why can't you just store the value in a javascript variable and reset the value based on that?

Comment: Ok, I have been really very confused with the DataTable's chronical problems and I would be appreciated if you post the answer by editing the code on my question. Thanks a lot...

Comment: @StephenMuecke Because the checkbox rendered during reload is also be reloaded as the datatable and for this reason I have to keep its value. On the other hand, what is the most suitable approach to retain this? Is it good idea to use cookie? If so, what do you suggest to retain the value? Is the approach in my code is ok or not?

Comment: Yes I know. but when you check/uncheck it you can assign its value, say `var isAllSelected = $('#cbIsAll).is(':checked');` and then after the datatable is reloaded - `$('#cbIsAll').prop('checked', isAllSelected);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke You rock as always!.. I really do not need to use cookie by using your trick and just needed to move **$('#cbIsAll').prop('checked', isAllSelected);** to the callback function (while debugging I saw that the checkbox is redrawn in the callback and I should set its value after redrawn). Many many thanks for your time -saver tricks and kind helps :) Regards...

Comment: @madalinivascu It would be better to post a useful comment instead of spending our time with verbose replies... I hope you follow the Stephen's steps, but seems to be impossible **verbose man** :)))

Comment: @ClintEastwood good for him :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use `$.cookie` in your case. In the checkbox `change` event, you can simply store the value of the checked state and use that to set the `checked` property of the new checkbox generated when you reload the table

```
var isChecked;
$(document).on('change', '#cbIsAll', function () {
    // Store the current value
    isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    ....
```

Then in the datatable's callback function, set the checked state of the checkbox

```
$('#cbIsAll').prop('checked', isChecked);
```

Comment: That is smart and quick solution with one of the best approach regarding to this issue. Many thanks for your useful tips and helps...